# Orden de ejecución de funciones no esperada en Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, function

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para un curso que estoy haciendo, en el que tengo que usar la API  de openweather.

Necesito comprobar si se logró traer la información solicitada mediante getJSON utilizando una bandera (booleana), pero la ejecución no sigue el orden esperado y luego de ejecutarse el get, la ejecución pasa al método "comprobar". También intenté capturar el error 404, que se produce cuando se introduce una ciudad no valida en la variable "city", pero no logré hacerlo

```
let enviar =document.querySelector("button");
let city = document.querySelector("#city")
let flag = false;
let a;
clima.on;
enviar.addEventListener("click",function(){    
   clima()
   comprobar() 
});

function clima(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city.value + "&appid=95176c8edea30e33338e0eaddd53a916&units=metric",function(data){
        document.querySelector(".container").style.visibility = "visible";    
        flag = true;
        
        let vars = data.main;
        let vars2 = data.sys;
        let vars3; 
        vars3 = (data.weather);
        document.querySelector("#ciudad").textContent = data.name;
        document.querySelector("#pais").textContent = vars2.country;
        document.querySelector("#temperatura").textContent = vars.temp;
        document.querySelector("#grados").innerHTML = "<sup>°C</sup>";
        document.querySelector("#wicon").setAttribute("src","http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+vars3[0].icon+".png");
        document.querySelector("#descripcion").textContent = vars3[0].description;
    
    })
}

function comprobar(){
   if(flag==false) {
       alert("error");
   } else {
       flag =false;
       alert("hola")
   }   
}
```

Comment: puedes quitar el `comprobar()` dentro del `addEventListener` de el boton, agrega el `comprobar()` dentro y al final de la funcion  `clima()`, prueba y dime si te funcionó

Comment: @enzo Ya lo había intentado, pero sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Comment: recuerda que `getJSON` recibe un callback, agrega la funcion `comprobar()` dentro y al final de ese callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema

El problema es que [$.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) es una función asíncrona.

Por lo tanto el programa segirá ejecutando la siguiente
función hasta que la API de openweather devuelva una respuesta.

Cuando la API devuelva una respuesta, el callback que enviaste como segundo parámetro de `getJSON(url, callback)`, va a manejar dicha respuesta.

Sin embargo, mientras la API no devuelva nada, la ejecución del programa seguirá normalmente, esto es para no bloquear el hilo principal de ejecución de Javascript.

### Solución

Para solucionar esto puedes hacer uso del método `.fail()` que devuelve la función `getJSON()` para comprobar si hubo un error (Dale en "Ejecutar" para verlo funcionando):

```js
let enviar = document.querySelector("#correcto");
let enviarErroneo = document.querySelector("#erroneo");
let city = document.querySelector("#city")
let flag = false;
let a;
clima.on;
enviar.addEventListener("click",function(){    
   clima("london");
   //comprobar() // No es necesario
});
enviarErroneo.addEventListener("click",function(){    
   clima("ciudadinexistente");
});

function clima(city){
    $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&appid=95176c8edea30e33338e0eaddd53a916&units=metric",
  function(data){ // Este es el callback que maneja la respuesta de la API
    document
      .querySelector(".container").style.visibility = "visible";    
        flag = true;
        let vars = data.main; // Te recomiendo que le des nombres descriptivos a las variables
        let vars2 = data.sys;
        let vars3; 
        vars3 = (data.weather);
        document.querySelector("#pais").textContent = vars2.country;
        document.querySelector("#temperatura").textContent = vars.temp;
        document.querySelector("#grados").innerHTML = "<sup>°C</sup>";
        document.querySelector("#wicon").setAttribute("src","http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+vars3[0].icon+".png");
        document.querySelector("#descripcion").textContent = vars3[0].description;
    
    })
  .fail(function() { // Si falla porque no encontró la ciudad, va a ejecutar esta función
    console.log( "error" );
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="correcto">Enviar</button>
<button id="erroneo">Enviar con error</button>
<div id="city">London</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="ciudad"></div>
  <div id="pais"></div>
  <div id="temperatura"></div>
  <div id="grados"></div>
  <div id="wicon"></div>
  <div id="descripcion"></div>
</div>
```

Te dejo algunos links para que leas más sobre asincronía en javascript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing